# How to validate a string whether it is alphanumeric

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

It might look simple but I cannot find a solution for this. In my application, I have many `UITextField`s. For example, let's say I have a `UITextField` called `textField`. When I enter a string into `textField`, I should validate whether string is alphanumeric. How can I do this?

I also have a button, apart from `textField`. After entering into `textField`, when I press button, I should validate whether the entered string is alphanumeric by showing it with `NSLog`. So can anyone help me solving this with some example or sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try following-

```
NSString *string = myTextField.text;
NSCharacterSet *alphanumericSet = [NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
BOOL isAplhaNumericOnly= [[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:alphanumericSet] isEqualToString:@""] && ![[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:numberSet] isEqualToString:@""];
```

This bool will return true only if your string is alphanumeric and not numeric only.

EDITED:-

To Log bool-

```
NSLog(@"isAplhaNumericOnly: %d",isAplhaNumericOnly);
```

And to return from this function -

```
if(isAplhaNumericOnly) {
    return;
}
```

Also if you want to show some alert then you can write code for presenting the alert above return statement.

Comment: so in  which function i should add this above code?so how do i check it in NSLog???

Comment: As you said that on click of button u need to validate, their you will check for these link if this is valid, and depending on the input you can return. Check edited post for logging bool.

Comment: i added this above code in -(IBAction)submit:(id)sender when i press submit button i want it to display in debugger whether its alphanumberic or number

Comment: Then you can log the string as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can NSLog BOOL values like this.

```
NSLog(@"Bool Value: %@",(isAplhaNumericOnly?@"YES":@"NO"));
```